# Restoring a SSD locked with HDD password

Tags: ssd, bios, encryption

Seeing that my Samsung 840 SSD has hardware encryption using the HDD-password from BIOS, I decided to try it out. Since there was no password before, I entered my password in the HDD password field in BIOS under security tab, then I saved and rebooted.

When my computer started up again, no boot options were available, even though the computer can see the SSD in the SATA port. (Not even USBs can be booted)

My intuition told me that if I remove the HDD password again, I'll get the SSD running, but to my surprise, **I cannot set the HDD password in the BIOS anymore.** All I can see is the "HDD Password Status: NOT INSTALLED".

I don't really care about any data on the disk - I just want it to work again. How can I remove the lock? Can I restore the SSD to factory settings?

- SSD: Samsung 840
- PC: Asus Vivobook S200, Intel i3-3217U
- BIOS: American Megatrends, Version 210

Picture of BIOS in the Security tab:

[image: BIOS]

Comment: If you enable Secure Boot Control does the SSD or USB drive show up then?

Comment: @Louis Yes, unfortunately, it makes no difference.
I have also been in the I/O Interface Security, but there are a lot of options I have no idea what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work be removing the SSD from the pc, booting into BIOS and resetting the HDD-password from there. After that, the SSD works just like before.

It seems like the BIOS should prompt be for the password before boot, **but didn't**, which locked my SSD.

I have not yet found a way to change the HDD-password for the SSD, nor how to make the HDD-password prompt appear. Since changing the hard drive in this notebook voids the warranty, it probably will never support that.